# Switch theme per user upon login

Tags: 6, theming, users

I'd like to switch theme per user upon user login success in my drupal 6 site. I need to check username of a particular user to change a particular theme for that user.
Is there any module around to accomplish this?
Or, do I have to write a hook like

```
function mymodule_init(){
    global $custom_theme;
    global $user;
    // check username here. 
    $custom_theme = 'garland';
}
```

But, I'm finding a module which have admin interface so that I can define usernames as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module which allows content, user, or role -specific themes.

Comment: The optional module ThemeKey User Profile that comes with theme key allows per user based theme.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the [Role Theme Switcher](http://drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) module?

Considering you have a limited number of themes and you can combine roles for a user, why not creating one specific role per theme that you will assign to your users.

Comment: Can I change theme per user of the same role?

Comment: Role theme switcher allows theme by role.. So obviously you cannot change theme per user of same role...